# Bad behavior ionic cordova release mode http and httpclient

Tags: cordova, http, ionic-framework, httpclient, release

in my app I have a login, in serve mode, lab and even with ionic cordoba run android in my device. But.. When I generate the release build, even with --prod. When I install the app in any device, my login doesn't work. I debug the app and I found that when I click in the Login button, the ejecution only go to my provider and dont return anything.

Time ago the releases that I generated, were working fine. But I don't know what can be. I also tried to change with observable, promises, http, httpclient but no success. Only in release mode doesn't work.

I tried with other computer, other project with only a button that request data, but same result in release mode, with debug mode works fine!.

Comment: it is a bit hard to answer without more precisions. Are you using tools that could process your code only when release is set? Something like `cordova-uglify` for example?

Comment: No, I don't. I tried creating a new project. `ionic start base blank` . I added a simple provider that fetches data, a button, a function in the ts file where the button is, called when the button is pressed, but same problem

Comment: could it be a CORS problem? Is your url different for release? You can try to search for browser errors (that sometimes can not appear in usual logs) by inspecting remote devices web pages (with chrome for android, or safari for ios)

Comment: I had a CORS problem time ago, but I fix it modifying htaccess. Anyways is the same URL for debug and release. Also tried with jsonplaceholder.typicode.com. But only the release is having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release mode turns on the HTTPS verification (I updated my SSL on my site and it worked)